# @types/reactとreactのversionが違うと問題でしょうか

Tags: reactjs, typescript

create react appで作られたversion 16のreact applicationにtypescriptを追加しています。
@types/reactと@types/react-domのversionについて、最新のv.18をインストールしたのですが、本体とversionが異なることが問題となるか教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantic versioning で言うところのメジャーバージョンとマイナーバージョンまでは揃えると良いです。パッチバージョンは最新まで上げてしまって大丈夫です。

[`@types/react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react) は [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) によって管理されている型定義ファイルのライブラリです。そして DefinitelyTyped の README に、提供するライブラリのバージョンについて以下のとおり書かれています：

> This is because only the major and minor release numbers are aligned between library packages and type declaration packages. The patch release number of the type declaration package (e.g. `.0` in `10.12.0`) is initialized to zero by Definitely Typed and is incremented each time a new `@types/node` package is published to npm for the same major/minor version of the corresponding library.

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#how-do-definitely-typed-package-versions-relate-to-versions-of-the-corresponding-library

つまり、たとえば `react` バージョン 16.9.0 をお使いなのであれば、`@types/react` の方は v16.9 系列のうちパッチバージョンが一番大きいもの（この回答が書かれた時点だとバージョン 16.9.56）を使えば良いです。

Comment: とても明瞭な回答ありがとうございます!
どこ調査したのかと、回答もわかりやすく、とても勉強になりました！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

基本的には、Versionは揃えるが正解のようだ。

型定義ファイルを自動でinstallしてくれる[typesync](https://github.com/jeffijoe/typesync)が便利そう。